# Integrate the react native package to expo

Tags: expo

We have a project where we want to integrate Didomi (react native package) but it does not support expo. To make it work we have to expo prebuild and do the following:
yarn add @didomi/react-native
cd ios and pod install
add didomi_config.json to ios direcotry and android/app/main/src/assets folder

Documentation: https://github.com/didomi/react-native

I tried the following with expo prebuild:

For Ios:

1. Expo Prebuild
2. cd ios
3. pod install
4. Manually add the didomi_config.json file to ios folder
5. Run on ios. It's working

For andorid

1. Manually add the didomi_config.json file to android/app/main/src/assests folder
2. Run on the android, Working fine.

But we want to integrate it with the help of expo plugin. Now the question is:
Are these steps possible using config plugin or expo module.
Specially, How do I copy the didomi_config.json to the respective folders without ejecting?